# Why do I need an __init__.py file to run pytest

Tags: python, pytest

My `conftest.py` file imports a function from a local module that's used when creating fixtures:

```
from config import dummy_func
```

I then use these fixtures in conjunction with a Hypothesis strategy.

The code hierarchy:

```
- src
  -config.py
- tests
   -conftest.py
   other test files
```

When I run `pytest`, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` for `config`.
If I add an empty `__init__.py` file to the tests directory, the test will run fine.  Why do we need it?

Note I'm not asking why we need `__init__.py` in general as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for), rather why we need it to get the `pytest` to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is \_\_init\_\_.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for)

Comment: No, doesn't.  I'm using the hypothesis with pytest frameworks and I want to understand why they're not able to load in the config module unless I have __init__.py in the tests directory.

Comment: Some additional clarification is needed.  What directory are you in when running pytest, and how exactly is it being invoked?  What is the target script for pytest --  ``pytest conftest.py`, `pytest config.py` or `pytest file_not_revealed.py`?  If it's some other file, does it directly import conftest.py or config.py?
If you use pytest fixtures without using hypothesis strategies, does the same issue occur?

Comment: I run `pytest` in the command line while in the project home directory (level above `src` and `tests`).  This tests all files with 'tests' in the name.  I don't know whether it works without hypothesis strategies.  Since the codebase uses hypothesis, I'd have to rewrite dummy tests to answer that question.

Comment: Are you simply running `pytest` or `python -m pytest`?  Are you using the default import-method of `prepend`, or `importlib`?  You may be able to avoid using `__init__.py` if you switch to importlib import method.  The Pytest docs have a bunch of explanation of the differences between the modes and the effect on different project layouts, but specifically, in prepend mode, it uses the existence of `__init__.py` files for test discovery and to find the base directory that should be added to `sys.path()` for imports.  Settings the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable could also be a solution

Comment: See some of the relevant documentation here: https://pytest.org/en/7.4.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery

Comment: As I wrote, I am simply running `pytest` and using defaults.